# weird issues when using styled-component in npm packages

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I'm trying to create a npm package - a UI component.

Let's say I have a project called `fancy-web`, and the npm package called `fancy-components`.

In `fancy-web`, I include in `package.json`

```
"fancy-components": "^0.0.1"
```

( In other words, `fancy-web` will consume `fancy-components` ).

---

In `fancy-web`, I have

```
// ...
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { Testing } from 'fancy-components';

// ...

return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Testing />
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

**The problem is here**

In my `fancy-components` **Testing** component, if I'm doing

```
If I'm doing something trivial like this in the Testing component, I will get an error

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

---

import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
  margin-top: 40px;
`;

function Testing(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>Testing</div>
    </Container>
  );

}

export default Testing;
```

```
However, the following works if my "Testing" component just like that. 

The following is the `Testing` code

---

import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';



function Testing(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
     <div>Testing</div>
  );

}

export default Testing;
```

Not sure what is wrong here and really appreciated of any help.

Comment: Seems like styled-component version that you use isn't compatible with hooks or your version of react isn't compatible with hooks

Comment: Please show the whole code and not snippets... Its clearly in `Testing` implementation

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm using `"styled-components": "^5.0.0"` on both project. And my react is `"react": "^16.8.6",`


@DennisVash I updated the `Testing` code.

Comment: the error message is very clear, is this the entire code? I think we need more information to find out the problem

Comment: Try to recreate the problem in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq, your code doesn't indicate any problem

Answer (score -1):

It turns out because I'm doing linking which cause the issues.  After I push it out instead of doing linking, everything works fine.